# UITextField text value returns garbage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to get a string value out of a textField when the user dismisses the keyboard. However, it seems that whenever I try to get the value, I get garbage (attempting to print out textField.text gives out garbage). What could I be doing wrong?

(The control displays fine, and I can put text values into it even).

Here's my code:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSInteger currenttag = textField.tag;

    NSLog(@"%d",textField.tag);

    if (currenttag == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%x %s",(unsigned int)textField.text,textField.text);
        username = textField.text;
    } else if (currenttag == 1) {
        password = textField.text;
    }

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

The fields username and passwords are nil NSString*'s, but since I will merely hold on to the NSStrings held by textField.text, it should be fine.

Comment: I assume that `username` and `password` are fields.  If so, you'll need to ensure that you retain them properly.

Comment: Can you show me a bit of code? Or is it something like 
[textField.text retain]?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"text field text:%@",textField.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using breakpoints? Have you tried `NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);` ?
Have you tried rewriting the function so it only displays the text?

Is the textField a valid object?

Comment: Checked via debugger, it is indeed a valid object with the text I entered through the UI earlier.

Comment: In the debugger, the text you've entered should then also be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting [textField retain]; as the 1st line will probably fix the problem. Just remember to add a [textField release]; at the end of the method.